# charting for Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2010 Express C#.  Is there a Microsoft Charting download for this?  It does not show in the toolbox but in the Choose Items - .Net Framework Components - System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting the check box is ticked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not disabled for Express.  You'll need to give more details, at least the kind of project template you are using.

Comment: It is a Window Forms Application.   As I said the Choose Items from the toolbox leads to a checked item for DataVisualisation but selecting that and clicking on browse takes me to a directory with various dlls but nothing recognisable as the Charts item

Comment: Don't click on Browse, ticking it is enough.  There are usually several that are named "Chart", be sure to pick the one with the "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting" namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the Data tab of the toolbox.

Comment: The toolbox does not have a Data Tab.  I tried Add Tab and typed in Data and it says there is already a tab named Data!  I bought a book Sams Visual C# 2010 and there is very little help with this sort of thing.   I come from a C, Delphi, Java background and the IDE for Visual C# is more labrynthine than any I have encountered so far and  I have not had much luck in finding a tutorial that gives help on this aspect.   So any suggestions would be useful...

Comment: Can access the chart now - The Choose Items on the toolbox popup menu   led to a tabbed dialog.   The chart option was checked in the .NET tab but not in the WPF tab.  Checking this fixed it.   Should I have got to this quicker ...... maybe.