# Add chart in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm searching for the chart in `visual basic 2010` and can't find it in `toolbox` .

What did i make wrong.

All windows forms objects exist except `Chart`

Comment: Duplicate of [charting for Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579423/charting-for-visual-studio-2010-express) ? Also worth reading [SocialMSDN - Chart Control in toolbox of visual studio 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/d4a7513c-d33c-495a-8301-8f973321a4a0/chart-control-in-toolbox-of-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer would be if you don't target the right .net Framework above 4.0 you won't be able to use Chart in visual basic 2010

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237(v=vs.110).aspx

Follow the steps below to add a chart control to your Windows Forms for Web application.
To add a chart control to your application
In design view, open the Toolbox.
From the Data category, drag a Chart control to the design area.
If you cannot see the Chart control in the Toolbox, right click in the Toolbox, select Choose Items, and then select the following namespaces in the .NET Framework Components tab:

System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: It was problem in targeting.